# XSD utility to convert XML to XSD and extra unwanted fields

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, xsd

I've used the XSD utility to convert an XML block that I have:

```
<parentsets>
<set name="aaa">
<GroupSet name="GS1" >
  <Group>Group1</Group>
  <Group>Group2</Group>
  <Group>Group3</Group>
</GroupSet>
<GroupSet name="GS2" >
  <Group>Group4</Group>
  <Group>Group5</Group>
  <Group>Group6</Group>
</GroupSet>
</set>
</parentsets>
```

I run the XSD utility which creates my XSD file.  I then run the utility again to convert my XSD to a C# sharp model (.cs).

The problem is that a lot of what I consider 'noise' is being created.  Firstly the XSD utility seems to have created some additional field first time around for the XSD file with the labels 'itemsField'.

And then there are what can only be described as duplicate branches e.g. The parent node 'pollingsets' is created again underneath with the label as 'pollingsetsSet'. Other nodes such as 'Group' become 'GroupField'.  All in all the generated XSD is a complete mess.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, perhaps some settings in the XML are required before running against the XSD utlity?

My aim is to create a model that matches my XML schema.  I then load the XML document and pass this to my corresponding model which is consumed by some business logic.  Hence why I've tried to go down the route of converting to XSD and then to a .cs file using the same XSD utility.

Thanks.

---

UPDATE

Example for XSD:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xs:schema id="parentsets" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
     <xs:element name="parentsets" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="en-US">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="set">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="GroupSet" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Group" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent msdata:ColumnName="Group_Text" msdata:Ordinal="0">
                          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                          </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

Comment: Post (a part of) the intermediate.XSD file. Did the tool understand your sample XML at all?  I doubt it will/can use those `name="..."` attributes.

Comment: Hi Henk, I've updated my question with an example snippet from the XSD.  :o)

Comment: You posted the .cs, not the .xsd. But indeed, no fields/properties named GS1 or aaa. You force the generator to add in extra layers.

Comment: opps my bad, I've manually opened it in a text editor as VS kept showing a visual diagram of it.  I've updated once again.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use one of the free online XML to XSD convertors found via a google search, seems to have helped cleanup some of the noise/mess that the XSD utility was putting in.